# eRROR With : Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, .net

I having some error here and i have no issue how to solve it .
it unable to call the list of the table

I try to call debug and when it reach the statement below

```
List<Int32> ListintNo = DT_ExcludeNo.AsEnumerable().Select(x
  =>Convert.ToInt32(x[0].ToString())).ToList();
```

Kindly assist .

```
 DataTable DT_ExcludeNo = new DataTable();
         dataAdapter.Fill(DT_ExcludeNo);

         InsertLogFile("AMB SP15: Validate Insert Data");

         //InsertLogFile("AMB SP15: Execute Query: " + sSqlCommandRetrieveExcludeNO);

         List<Int32> ListintNo = DT_ExcludeNo.AsEnumerable().Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x[0].ToString())).ToList();
        for (Int32 i = 1; i <= TotalCount; i++)
        {
            foreach (Int32 intNo in ListintNo)
            {
                if (i == intNo)
                {
                string sSqlCommandRetrieveData = "SELECT Name, [I.C], [D.O.B], NO, [EFF DATE], Sum_Insured from AMB_Temp WHERE NO = " + i;

                SqlCommand obj_SQLCommand = new SqlCommand(sSqlCommandRetrieveData, myconn);
                dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(obj_SQLCommand);

                DataSet DS_RetrieveData = new DataSet();
                dataAdapter.Fill(DS_RetrieveData);

                //InsertLogFile("AMB SP15: Execute Query: " + sSqlCommandRetrieveData);

                DataValidation(DS_RetrieveData);
                }
```

Comment: show us the stack trace or line that the exception happens on and what the values of the parameters, if any, were. you also don't show us the code snippet of what x[0] actually is. what is "x"? what value is it? what type of object is it? What is in the data at that index?

Comment: Hi tha line of exception happens on  : 
List ListintNo = DT_ExcludeNo.AsEnumerable().Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x[0].ToString())).ToList();

Comment: the value of dataTable No was number / nvarchar

Comment: In Linq datatypes are not able to convert at runtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the updated code:

```
//start new code
string fieldString = x[0].ToString();
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fieldString))
{
   fieldString = "0";
}
//InsertLogFile("AMB SP15: Execute Query: " + sSqlCommandRetrieveExcludeNO);

List<Int32>    ListintNo = DT_ExcludeNo.AsEnumerable().Select(x =>   Convert.ToInt32(fieldString )).ToList();
//end new code
     DataTable DT_ExcludeNo = new DataTable();
     dataAdapter.Fill(DT_ExcludeNo);

     InsertLogFile("AMB SP15: Validate Insert Data");

     //InsertLogFile("AMB SP15: Execute Query: " + sSqlCommandRetrieveExcludeNO);
        string fieldString = x[0].ToString();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fieldString))
        { fieldString = "0"; }

     List<Int32> ListintNo = DT_ExcludeNo.AsEnumerable().Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(fieldString)).ToList();



        for (Int32 i = 1; i <= TotalCount; i++)
    {
        foreach (Int32 intNo in ListintNo)
        {
            if (i == intNo)
            {
            string sSqlCommandRetrieveData = "SELECT Name, [I.C], [D.O.B], NO, [EFF DATE], Sum_Insured from AMB_Temp WHERE NO = " + i;

            SqlCommand obj_SQLCommand = new SqlCommand(sSqlCommandRetrieveData, myconn);
            dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(obj_SQLCommand);

            DataSet DS_RetrieveData = new DataSet();
            dataAdapter.Fill(DS_RetrieveData);

            //InsertLogFile("AMB SP15: Execute Query: " + sSqlCommandRetrieveData);

            DataValidation(DS_RetrieveData);
            }
```

Comment: nope. you don't need to do that. It will still compile fine. The original error is a RUNTIME error also.

Comment: I assume it happens when dataAdapter.Fill method is invoked using the dynamic sql. The sqlcommand takes a string as a parameter, but at runtime it is assigned a string plus an int.

Comment: the Error occur die at line :

List ListintNo = DT_ExcludeNo.AsEnumerable().Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x[0].ToString())).ToList();

Comment: Have you checked for nulls - e.g. if( String.IsNullOrEmpty(x[0].ToString()) then set it to 0

Comment: hi Robert, 
can you please provide some sample code ? as im newbie on code thanks

Comment: Sure, I will update the answer to include the code

Comment: Hi robert , i get some error when try to paste your code :

string fieldString = x[0].ToString();  <<< as the x

Comment: What does it say? You may want to also write some code to handle non numeric conversion - e.g. if int.parse fails then set it to 0

Comment: DataTable DT_ExcludeNo = new DataTable();
             dataAdapter.Fill(DT_ExcludeNo);

             InsertLogFile("AMB SP15: Validate Insert Data");
             string fieldString = x[0].ToString();

             if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fieldString))
             {
                 fieldString = "0";
             }
             //InsertLogFile("AMB SP15: Execute Query: " + sSqlCommandRetrieveExcludeNO);

            List<Int32> ListintNo = DT_ExcludeNo.AsEnumerable().Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x[0].ToString())).ToList();

Comment: it was saying x doesnt exist

Comment: You just need to put it in the right place. I will update my answer with the full code.

Comment: OK it is updated now, when you get a chance it would be good to also use int.parse just to check whether x[0].ToString() is actually a nunmber, then set it to 0 if it isnt.

Comment: hi robert... it still same error  

x[0].ToString(); <<< encounter error with x not exist

Answer (score 0):

Please check your database column field datatype of `NO` if it is `VarChar or Char` the you have to change your where statement.

```
string sSqlCommandRetrieveData = "SELECT Name, [I.C], [D.O.B], NO, [EFF DATE], Sum_Insured from   AMB_Temp WHERE NO = " + Convert. ToString(i);
```

Comment: Hi , is NVARCHAR IS THAT POSSIBLE TO PUT THAT STATEMENT ON ?

Comment: As per my understanding of your question `NvarChar` is possible on that statement.